# Recover text of deleted question

Tags: support

This question looks like it was posted by a sleezy SEO operation

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712799/looking-for-the-best-dentist-in-vancouver

I wanted to see if I could quickly google the dentist office involved and email them what their SEO firm is "doing" for them, but the text was changed (appropriately) to SPAM SPAM...  Any way to recover the original post?

Comment: Aren't you able to see the revision history along with the question?

Comment: 10k's can see the post and the original content.  Though I don't think sharing it here would be productive (then the links would be public again).  Your best bet is probably to email the team using the `contact us` link at the bottom of the page.  Here's the email listed there: team@stackoverflow.com.  But fortunately you're a 10k so you should be able to see it yourself in the revision history.

Comment: By 10k, do you mean 10k in total SE reputation? Or only reputation on a single SE?

Comment: @InquilineKea single SE. Reputation and privileges are granted independently on each SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were links to `vancouverdentistvancouver` and `northvandentist`, both `.com` domains.

You can see the original post using the revision history (10K only):

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6712799/revisions

You can find the revision history on the link above the box saying who edited it and when (same as all posts on stack overflow):

> edited **[31 mins ago](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6712799/revisions)**

Comment: Note: Only mods/10k+ users will be able to see the post revision history  (Eric J will be able to though, so this is a good suggestion!)

Comment: Probably being totally blind, but where's the revisions link?  (or do you just need to know the URL)

Comment: @Eric - it was edited by Neil Knight. The link is where it says "edited **[31 mins ago](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6712799/revisions)**", same as all posts on stack overflow.

Comment: @Kobi - I see now... I have to click on the 31 minutes ago part.